# console.log / Select single key from array?

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax, django-rest-framework

I set up a django REST framework API, it´s connected to a django model with random data. I am able to load the API Data, in a JSON Format, into a HTML Box after pressing a button. i called it **JSON Data Finder**

```
<div class="container-fluid">

<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        document.getElementById('getJSONdataTest').onclick = function () {
            req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            req.open("GET", 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/cars/', true);
            req.send();
            req.onload = function () {
                json = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
                document.getElementsByClassName('data box')[0].innerHTML = JSON.stringify(json);
                console.log(json);
                // Print
            };
        };
    });
</script>
<style>

    body {
        text-align: center;
        font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;
    }

    h1 {
        font-size: 2em;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .box {
        border-radius: 5px;
        background-color: #eee;
        padding: 20px 5px;
    }

    button {
        color: white;
        background-color: #4791d0;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #4791d0;
        padding: 5px 10px 8px 10px;
    }

        button:hover {
            background-color: #0F5897;
            border: 1px solid #0F5897;
        }
</style>
<h1>JSON Data Finder</h1>
<p class="data box">
    The Data will go here
</p>
<p>
    <button id="getJSONdataTest">
        Get Data
    </button>
</p>
```

this is the output in my **JSON Data Finder** when i click the Button:

> {"count":4,"next":null,"previous":null,"results":[{"id":3,"name":"Audi","price":11},{"id":2,"name":"Mercedes","price":22},{"id":1,"name":"BMW","price":99},{"id":4,"name":"Trabant","price":113}]}

**---------------------------**

Now i would like to target a specific object or value of a key, after pressing the button.

example:

```
console.log(json[2].name);
```

So the Output should show me the name of object 3

> Audi

**---------------------------**

unfortunately nothing happens and the console displayed a error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
>       at XMLHttpRequest.req.onload ((index):111)

i guess that JavaScript can not interpret my Output because the Array is not "clean"? because of this

> {"count":4,"next":null,"previous":null,

in front of my result?

> "results":[{"id":3,"name":"Audi","price":11},{"id":2,"name":"Mercedes","price":22},{"id":1,"name":"BMW","price":99},{"id":4,"name":"Trabant","price":113}]}

Comment: Looks to me like you want json.results[2].name, which in that array would return "BMW", as that's the name in the third element in the array. If you're looking for the result with an id of 3, you're going to need to search the results array for that id.

Comment: `json.results[0].name` should give you audi, the error is hapening because the way you are console logging, it is going into `"next": null,` and then trying to look for `name` after that. Which doesn't exist because it is not an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> javaScript can not interpret my Output because the Array is not "clean"

Your `json` object is not an unclean array; it's not an array at all. It's a JS object ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics)).

Once you've read up on JS objects, the error become obvious. But to summarize, `json` is neither an array nor has a field named `2`. Hence `json[2]` returns undefined, and `undefined.name` throws an error.

To get `Audi`, you require `json.results[0].name`

Comment: Thanks works. So it´s a JS object because it is in `{ }` .

Comment: correct. on the other hand, arrays are wrapped in `[ ]`